# Why `inject.js loaded` messeage is printed when I turn on Developer Tool - Console Tab on Chrome

Tags: javascript

I found that whenever I turn on the Developer tool and see Console Tab, `inject.js loaded` message is printed.

For example, I opened the following code using Chrome:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
                console.log(i);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        for statement
    </body>
</html>
```

0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 are printed and `inject.js loaded` messeage is also printed at the end, as follows:
[image]

However, I found that the `inject.js loaded` messeage is not printed when I run the same code in private mode of Chrome follows:

[image]

The message is printed because `inject.js` includes the code `console.log('inject.js loaded')`. Is there any reason the `inject.js` is run although I did not create the file? and why the messeage is not printed in a private mode?

Comment: That should be an extension you have installed in Chrome especially when the message doesn't appear in incognito mode.

Comment: Aha, then it is my personal issue, not a general browser thing. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `inject.js` is loaded by one of your browser plugins, and in private mode, all plugins are default to disabled.

Comment: Aha, then it is my personal issue, not a general browser thing. Thx